# $A_n=\{\{k_1,...,k_n\}|\sum\limits_{I=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k_i}=1, k_i\in Z^+\}$, finding a formula for $|A_n|$

Tags: combinatorics

I am sure this is like some super classic combinatorics problem, but as I have not been able to find it, I decided to post.

Given the set :

$A_n=\{\{k_1,...,k_n\}|\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k_i}=1, k_i\in Z^+\}$

I want to find a way to obtain a formula for $|A_n|$. I don't think I have the sufficient tools to approach this problem.

Comment: if anything else, you can know the size of $A_1$ is 1, and the size of $A_{\infty}$ is infinite, given $A_{\infty} = {2, 4, 8, 16, \dots}$

Comment: Also, this problem seems very closely linked to the Erdős-Graham Conjecture

Comment: @RobBland In what way?

Comment: Well, it proves that $A_n$ exists for every $n \in Bbb{N}$. It's possible to find a subset of integers of any size whose reciprocals sum to 1

Comment: You should look at the Wikipedia page on Egyptian fractions, it might have something you need to get started

Comment: @RobBland $A_n$ is a collection of sets, so those elements aren't in $A_\infty$,

Comment: Ahhh, okay, I see now. I misunderstood the original statement

Comment: " The number of different n-term Egyptian fraction representations of the number one is bounded above and below by double exponential functions of n.[15]" -from the Wikipedia page on Egyptian fractions